# How to read the pkcs12 file content?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, keystore, pkcs#12

I am trying to load a KeyStore from a pkcs12(.p12) file, but exactly when I call the KeyStore.load(stream, password), JVM throws a RuntimeExcepction: Error creating Key, I can write on the pkcs12 and I can even import it on navigator, but I cant read it in my code.

The code that saves the KeyStore on disk:

```
public static void gerarPkcs12(PrivateKey chavePrivada, X509Certificate certificado, String caminhoPkcs12,
        String alias, char[] senha) {
        try {
    KeyStore repositorio = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
            repositorio.load(null, senha);
            Certificate[] chain = {certificado};
            repositorio.setKeyEntry(alias, chavePrivada, senha, chain);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(caminhoPkcs12);
            repositorio.store(fos, senha);
        } catch(KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | NoSuchProviderException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
}
```

The code which tries to read it from the file

```
 80. KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
 81. FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(caminhoPkcs12Usuario);
 82. BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
 83. ks.load(bis, "1234".toCharArray());
```

And the StackTrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: error creating key
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.createSubjectKeyId(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.access$100(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi$CertId.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
at etapas.QuartaEtapa.main(QuartaEtapa.java:83)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there more of that stack trace? a 'caused by' exception? And why are you using BC? The JRE has a PKCS#12 keystore provider.

Comment: And are `caminhoPkcs12` and `caminhoPkcs12Usuario` the same value? NB You aren't closing the `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: @EJP: the throw in PKCS12KeyStoreStpi.createSubjectKeyId does not set cause, though it probably should; and this gets called only after parsing the whole P12 and verifying the HMAC, so the file contents must be complete even without having closed. OP: on the write side, how was `certificado` created? what 'navigator' is able to read this? can `openssl pkcs12` read it successfully and if so does `openssl x509 -text` work on the result? can you try the Sun-now-Oracle implementation (provider), which (at least in j8) uses different logic to match bag-elements?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 It should throw something that extends `GeneralSecuriyyException` or whatever it is allowed to throw, and it should contain a much more informative error message.

Comment: @EJP thank you, dont set BouncyCastle as provider solved the problem, and I also have forget to close the `FileOutputStream` , but it seems that this was not the problem.